# Does this CPU fit with the GPU?

Tags: graphics-cards, processor, motherboard, desktop, power-supply

Apparently this CPU is a bad combination with my GPU; I have been told that they will not work together. These are the main parts:

1. AMD - Ryzen 7 1700 3.0GHz 8-Core Processor (No overclocking so do I need CPU cooler separate?)
2. MSI - A320M BAZOOKA Micro ATX AM4 Motherboard
3. Gigabyte - GeForce GTX 1050 2GB G1 Gaming Video Card
4. Areocool P7 C1 Case
5. EVGA - 500W 80+ Bronze Certified ATX Power Supply

There will no intense programming or video processing; I will use the PC for some games here and there, but it will only be doing regular "home" tasks everyday.

Please, anyone who states a price for an item, mention the currency you're talking about. If it is USD or something, then say so, for the benefit of anyone reading this.

---

**EDIT:**

What is the best AM4 motherboard to get? The MSI Bazooka is a good option, but it is kind of reddish, and I am going for a black/blue set up.

**EDIT 2:**

I considered jcam3's answer, and refined my build. Remaining is one concern:

The CRYORIG C7 compatibility, and whether it has its own LED's (because I can't find that info about it). I don't want it to have LED's, so if it does, is there a better recommendation? [**Here is the final link**](https://au.pcpartpicker.com/list/cBkrHh).

Comment: "I have been told that they will not work together."  By who?  Since you're only doing "home" tasks, why the 1700 and not say 1500?  It would be cheaper and still give good power.

Comment: Echoing @SiXandSeven8ths. They're completely compatible, but it's a rather weird system to build.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths Why?

Answer (score 5):

> Apparently this CPU is a bad combination with my GPU; I have been told that they will not work together.

## That CPU and GPU will work together just fine.

GPU's are designed to be compatible with most CPU architectures, including offerings from Intel and AMD. Ryzen is AMD's new platform, and just like any new release there were some kinks to work out in regard to memory management and driver / system compatibility. Ryzen CPU's have been out for a while, so as far as I know those issues are all resolved. I have several friends and co-workers running Ryzen systems, running a mix of GPU's from both Nvidia and AMD. No major or irregular problems reported.

---

> No overclocking so do I need CPU cooler separate?

## You do not need an aftermarket cooler for any Ryzen CPU if you're not overclocking.

Even if you are overclocking, the "Spire" cooler series (which come stock with Ryzen chips) are very good air coolers. I'd recommend you save your cash and use the stock cooler. You can always buy a big fancy one later if you end up wanting to do extreme overclocking down the line.

---

> There will no intense programming or video processing; I will use the PC for some games here and there, but it will only be doing regular "home" tasks everyday.

So I know this part wasn't really a question, but I do have a recommendation or two.

First, the CPU you're getting is probably overkill for  your goals. It offers some future proofing and flexibility, but as @SiXandSeven8ths mentioned already in the comments you'd probably get equivalent use from a Ryzen 5 series unless you're going to be doing VR gaming.

Second, if you do go with the Ryzen 7 1700, get the Ryzen 7 1700x instead. They're the same price, but the 1700x is a better "binned" chip. This means it'll be faster and more stable on average.

---

www.pcpartpicker.com is a good ressource to use. I've got your build started for you at the following link:

https://pcpartpicker.com/list/gyy23b

Good luck with the build!

---

## Regarding questions from OP's edits:

I like the board in your PCPartPicker list a lot. I've had good experiences with ASUS motherboards and from what I've heard they handled the release of DDR4 and the new socket types with minimal speed bumps.

The CRYORIG C7 cooler will work just fine. It's designed to fit the following sockets according to PCPartPicker:

> AM2, AM2+, AM3, AM3+, AM4, FM1, FM2, FM2+, LGA1150, LGA1151, LGA1155, LGA1156

I don't believe it has any LED's, or at least I can't find any pictures or documentation suggesting that it does. Most coolers that *do* feature LED lighting have them installed directly on the fans, which are replaceable anyhow. I'd say that you've got a green light to go ahead and get the C7, as the worst case scenario is replacing an LED enabled fan with a non-LED fan.

Please let me know if you have additional questions, I'll be happy to follow up. Best of luck with the build!

Comment: As a matter of fact, I have been using pcpartpicker. But I should probably mention that I want to be good without any upgrades for the next couple of years. Is a Ryzen 5 still the way to go?

Comment: I would say yes, the Ryzen 5 is the better pick unless: 1.) budget is not a concern or 2.) you know that you have workloads that would benefit from the extra cores. Examples of such workloads would be rendering, video editing, compiling code, etc.

Comment: What level of code compile? I usually work with winforms on VS2015

Comment: Will the CRYORIG C7 do?

Comment: @TGamer I looked over your additional questions and have added an edit to the bottom portion of my response reflecting my best answers to them.

Comment: But see [this](http://www.cryorig.com/c7_us.php) it doesn't show AM4 under supported motherboards